# How to keep the chat going when one of clients disconnects in round robin chat system

Tags: python

Im implementing Client Server round robin chat system. Following is my thread on the server side which accepts connections

```
def multipleClients():
    conn, addr = s.accept()    
    all_clients.append(conn)
    print len(all_clients)
    while True:
        if len(all_clients)>=2:
        for sockets in all_clients :
            # receive, retransmit, etc..
            sockets.send("You: ")
            sockets.settimeout(20)
                        try:
                            data= sockets.recv(1024)

                            if len(data) == 0:
                                print "no data recieved"
                                break
                            sockets.send("You can't send message for now ^_^")
                            print repr(name),":"
                            print "message is :", repr(data)
                            for c in all_clients:               
                                    c.send(data)
                        except timeout:
                            print repr(name),"HAHAHAHAHAHHAHAHA TIMEOUT TIMEOUT"
                            sockets.send("You have timed out")
        else:
             conn.send("Wait for other users to connect")
             break;
```

What I want to implement is that when one of the clients forcibly closes the connection then Server doesnt throw an exception but keeps the chat going and my array all_clients[] is updated. Kindly tell me how I can implement it.